# open, write and close file in a one-liner

Tags: python, pathlib

I found a sample code in [pathlib reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) and I wonder how can I close this opened file.

```
p = Path('foo')
p.open('w').write('some text')
```

I tried to close file.

```
Path('foo').open('w').write('some text').close()
```

It caused `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'close'` and I understood why it caused error with this sentence as below.

> Python file method write() writes a string str to the file. There is no return value

But how can I close this.

Comment: What's wrong with just defining your own method for that?

Comment: **Why** do you need it to be a one liner? What's wrong with `with` clause?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Do you mean it's impossible to close opened file after this ? `p.open('w').write('some text')`

Comment: Your reason is incorrect. The `write` method returns the number of characters written to the file. And you cannot call `close` on a number, as it has no meaning. Trying to do all these things in a single line serves no purpose, as the Python interpreter will still need to break it down into its constituent parts, and run them separately.

Comment: Do the correct thing, use `with`.

Comment: @matszwecja sometimes it's about exploring how language works and what are its limits.

Comment: @mx0 But it's not clear from the question that is the goal, that's why I asked the OP.

Comment: @matszwecja My goal is to understand the [pathlib's sample code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename). I didn't mean I want to do it one-liner. But I want to understand how to close the file after opened with the way like the sample code as.

Comment: @CatBraaain In that case, as others have said - `.close` is a method of a file. You get file object from `.open` method. If you chain `.close` after `.write`, you are trying to call it on a number (returned from write) instead of that file.

Comment: @matszwecja Okay. I understand chained `.close` method not working after `write()`. But the sample code didn't get file object from `.open`. Why is it, and is there any way to close opened file without file object. How can I apply the sample to my code.

Comment: @CatBraaain The sample code does not close the file at all. Why is that, only someone who wrote it can tell for sure, but most likely is that because it's not relevant to what the sample is trying to show (how `.rename` works). And again, why would you not have a file object for a file you are trying to close? What is the actual problem you are solving?

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks for answering. I just wanted to learn and practice how to manipulate files from the sample. I don't have any problem to solve in my project. I'm new to post question and also English.  Now I guess something wrong in my way to ask. I will try make it better next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pathlib.Path.write_text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text) function to write to file and close it in one line:

> Open the file pointed to in text mode, write data to it, and close the file:

```
Path('foo').write_text('some text')
```

You can't use `.close()` after `.write()` function because `.write()` returns number of characters written to a file (int).

There is also a [pathlib.Path.read_text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) function to read contents of a file and close it in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly assume that chained `close()` is called on file handle context. It is not. The line:

```
Path('foo').open('w').write('some text').close()
```

can be split into

```
a = Path('foo')
b = a.open('w')
c = b.write('some text')
c.close()
```

and it makes no much sense because `write()` returns number of bytes written, not a handle, so `c` is an `integer` and the error now should be more clear. So do not optimize prematurely when not needed:

```
p = Path('foo')
handle = p.open('w')
handle.write('some text')
handle.close();
```

BUT, this is not pythonic. You should go with `with`:

```
with Path('foo').open('w') as handle:
   handle.write('some text')
```

and that would handle file closing for you.

Comment: And the final version *could* be written on one line, but there's no compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Exactly. The fact you can does not mean you should.